# Solaris10 Hard Disk Information

Tags: raid, solaris, serial, drive

I am trying to inventory hard disk information remotely (serial number, disk size, manufacturer...) but am having trouble. I know the drive(s) are configured under a raid controller, but can I view this information without rebooting? So far I've tried the following:

```
format
Searching for disks...done


AVAILABLE DISK SELECTIONS:
   0. c0t2d0 <DEFAULT cyl 8872 alt 2 hd 255 sec 63>
      /pci@0,0/pci1022,7450@2/pci1000,3060@3/sd@2,0




iostat -E
sd0       Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 2 Transport Errors: 0
Vendor: AMI      Product: Virtual CDROM    Revision: 1.00 Serial No:
Size: 0.00GB <0 bytes>
Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 2 Recoverable: 0
Illegal Request: 4 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0
sd2       Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 0 Transport Errors: 0
Vendor: TEAC     Product: DV-28SL          Revision: 1.0A Serial No:
Size: 0.00GB <0 bytes>
Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 0 Recoverable: 0
Illegal Request: 6 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0
sd3       Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 2 Transport Errors: 0
Vendor: AMI      Product: Virtual Floppy   Revision: 1.00 Serial No:
Size: 0.00GB <0 bytes>
Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 2 Recoverable: 0
Illegal Request: 4 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0
sd5       Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 0 Transport Errors: 0
Vendor: LSILOGIC Product: Logical Volume   Revision: 3000 Serial No:
Size: 73.00GB <72999763456 bytes>
Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 0 Recoverable: 0
Illegal Request: 2 Predictive Failure Analysis: 0




cfgadm -alv
Ap_Id                          Receptacle   Occupant     Condition  Information
When         Type         Busy     Phys_Id
c0                             connected    configured   unknown
unavailable  scsi-bus     n        /devices/pci@0,0/pci1022,7450@2/pci1000,3060@3:scsi
c0::dsk/c0t2d0                 connected    configured   unknown    LSILOGIC Logical         Volume
unavailable  disk         n            /devices/pci@0,0/pci1022,7450@2/pci1000,3060@3:scsi::dsk/c0t2d0
usb0/1                         empty        unconfigured ok
unavailable  unknown      n        /devices/pci@0,0/pci1022,7460@6/pci1022,7464@0:1
usb0/2                         empty        unconfigured ok
unavailable  unknown      n        /devices/pci@0,0/pci1022,7460@6/pci1022,7464@0:2
usb0/3                         connected    configured   ok         Mfg: American     Megatrends Inc.  Product: Virtual Keyboard and Mouse  NConfigs: 1  Config: 0  <no cfg str     descr>
unavailable  usb-device   n        /devices/pci@0,0/pci1022,7460@6/pci1022,7464@0:3
usb1/1                         connected    configured   ok         Mfg: American     Megatrends Inc.  Product: Virtual Cdrom Device  NConfigs: 1  Config: 0  <no cfg str descr>
unavailable  usb-storage  n        /devices/pci@0,0/pci1022,7460@6/pci1022,7464@0,1:1
usb1/2                         connected    configured   ok         Mfg: American     Megatrends Inc.  Product: Virtual Floppy Device  NConfigs: 1  Config: 0  <no cfg str descr>
unavailable  usb-floppy   n        /devices/pci@0,0/pci1022,7460@6/pci1022,7464@0,1:2
usb1/3                         empty        unconfigured ok
unavailable  unknown      n        /devices/pci@0,0/pci1022,7460@6/pci1022,7464@0,1:3



prtdiag
System Configuration: Sun Microsystems Sun Fire X4200 Server
BIOS Configuration: American Megatrends Inc. 080010  08/10/2005
BMC Configuration: IPMI 2.0 (KCS: Keyboard Controller Style)

==== Processor Sockets ====================================

Version                          Location Tag
-------------------------------- --------------------------
Dual Core AMD Opteron(tm) Processor 275 H0
Dual Core AMD Opteron(tm) Processor 275 H1
Dual Core AMD Opteron(tm) Processor 275 H2
Dual Core AMD Opteron(tm) Processor 275 H3

==== Memory Device Sockets ================================

Type    Status Set Device Locator      Bank Locator
------- ------ --- ------------------- --------------------
DDR     in use 0   H0_DIMM0            BANK0
DDR     in use 0   H0_DIMM1            BANK1
unknown empty  0   H0_DIMM2            BANK2
unknown empty  0   H0_DIMM3            BANK3
DDR     in use 0   H1_DIMM0            BANK4
DDR     in use 0   H1_DIMM1            BANK5
DDR     in use 0   H1_DIMM2            BANK6
DDR     in use 0   H1_DIMM3            BANK7

==== On-Board Devices =====================================
 LSI serial-ATA #1
 Gigabit Ethernet #1
 Gigabit Ethernet #2
 ATI Rage XL VGA

==== Upgradeable Slots ====================================

ID  Status    Type             Description
--- --------- ---------------- ----------------------------
0   in use    PCI-X            PCIX SLOT0
1   available PCI-X            PCIX SLOT1
2   available PCI-X            PCIX SLOT2
3   available PCI-X            PCIX SLOT3
4   available PCI-X            PCIX SLOT4



raidctl -l
Controller: 0
    Volume:c0t2d0
    Disk: 0.2.0
    Disk: 0.3.0
```

Answer (score 1):

As this is an LSI controller, you should be using the [MegaCLI](http://www.lsi.com/sep/Pages/oracle/sg_x_sas6-r-int-z.aspx) command line utility to retrieve information about the physical drives attached:

```
./MegaCLI -PDList -aAll
```